# AngularJS change locale file on lang change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have an angularJS application with multiple language support.

In our main app module, we defined:

```
.config(function ($translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useLoader("$translatePartialLoader", {
        urlTemplate: "/js/app/i18n/{lang}.json"
    });
    $translateProvider
    .registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en', 'fr'], {
        'en_US': 'en',
        'en_UK': 'en',
        'en_CA': 'en',
        'fr_FR': 'fr',
        'fr_CA': 'fr',
        'fr_BE': 'fr',
        '*': 'en'
    })
    .fallbackLanguage('en')
    .determinePreferredLanguage();
```

In our main controller, we have a select to change the lang, calling this function:

```
this.changeLang = function () {
        $translate.use(self.currentLang).then(function () {
            // Here we want to trigger the call to another angular i8ln file
        }, function () {
            MessageService.show("error", $translate.instant("lang_change_error"));
        });
    };
```

But we want to use angular i8ln power to translate some data, for example datepickers.

We understood we have to load **angular i8ln locale files** in our index.html where the angular app is loaded. These files contain for example:

```
'use strict';
angular.module("ngLocale", [], ["$provide", function ($provide) {
    var PLURAL_CATEGORY = { ZERO: "zero", ONE: "one", TWO: "two", FEW: "few", MANY: "many", OTHER: "other" };
    function getDecimals(n) {
        n = n + '';
        var i = n.indexOf('.');
        return (i == -1) ? 0 : n.length - i - 1;
    }

    function getVF(n, opt_precision) {
        var v = opt_precision;

        if (undefined === v) {
            v = Math.min(getDecimals(n), 3);
        }

        var base = Math.pow(10, v);
        var f = ((n * base) | 0) % base;
        return { v: v, f: f };
    }

    $provide.value("$locale", {
        "DATETIME_FORMATS": {
            "AMPMS": [
              "AM",
              "PM"
            ],
            "DAY": [
              "Sunday",
              "Monday",
              "Tuesday",
              "Wednesday",
              "Thursday",
              "Friday",
              "Saturday"
            ],
            "ERANAMES": [
              "Before Christ",
              "Anno Domini"
            ],
            "ERAS": [
              "BC",
              "AD"
            ],
            "FIRSTDAYOFWEEK": 6,
            "MONTH": [
              "January",
              "February",
              "March",
              "April",
              "May",
              "June",
              "July",
              "August",
              "September",
              "October",
              "November",
              "December"
            ],
            "SHORTDAY": [
              "Sun",
              "Mon",
              "Tue",
              "Wed",
              "Thu",
              "Fri",
              "Sat"
            ],
            "SHORTMONTH": [
              "Jan",
              "Feb",
              "Mar",
              "Apr",
              "May",
              "Jun",
              "Jul",
              "Aug",
              "Sep",
              "Oct",
              "Nov",
              "Dec"
            ],
            "STANDALONEMONTH": [
              "January",
              "February",
              "March",
              "April",
              "May",
              "June",
              "July",
              "August",
              "September",
              "October",
              "November",
              "December"
            ],
            "WEEKENDRANGE": [
              5,
              6
            ],
            "fullDate": "EEEE, MMMM d, y",
            "longDate": "MMMM d, y",
            "medium": "MMM d, y h:mm:ss a",
            "mediumDate": "MMM d, y",
            "mediumTime": "h:mm:ss a",
            "short": "y-MM-dd h:mm a",
            "shortDate": "y-MM-dd",
            "shortTime": "h:mm a"
        },
        "NUMBER_FORMATS": {
            "CURRENCY_SYM": "$",
            "DECIMAL_SEP": ".",
            "GROUP_SEP": ",",
            "PATTERNS": [
              {
                  "gSize": 3,
                  "lgSize": 3,
                  "maxFrac": 3,
                  "minFrac": 0,
                  "minInt": 1,
                  "negPre": "-",
                  "negSuf": "",
                  "posPre": "",
                  "posSuf": ""
              },
              {
                  "gSize": 3,
                  "lgSize": 3,
                  "maxFrac": 2,
                  "minFrac": 2,
                  "minInt": 1,
                  "negPre": "-\u00a4",
                  "negSuf": "",
                  "posPre": "\u00a4",
                  "posSuf": ""
              }
            ]
        },
        "id": "en",
        "localeID": "en",
        "pluralCat": function (n, opt_precision) { var i = n | 0; var vf = getVF(n, opt_precision); if (i == 1 && vf.v == 0) { return PLURAL_CATEGORY.ONE; } return PLURAL_CATEGORY.OTHER; }
    });
}]);
```

**But how to load the i8ln file depending on what lang is currently loaded?**

I tried to change the `<script>` src  using `ng-if` trick or string interpolation but it's forbidden to prevent XSS injection.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about it. Will definitely have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Jack A. advice, you can easily use angular-dynamic-locale module. This module allows you to "trigger" the include of a locale file using a simple function.

Here are the steps you can follow:

### Include the Angular Dynamic Local module on your project

You just have to follow the steps on the [module README](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale/blob/master/README.md#user-content-usage).

Especially, don't forget :

- Include the `tmhDynamicLocaleProvider` module in your modules array: Include the `tmhDynamicLocaleProvider` module in your modules array in your main App module file: **`angular.module("yourApp", ["tmh.dynamicLocale", ... ]);`**
- In your main App Module to change the locale Location config

It should looks like:

```
.config(function ($translateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {
    $translateProvider.useLoader("$translatePartialLoader", {
        urlTemplate: "/js/app/i18n/{lang}.json"
    });
    $translateProvider
    .registerAvailableLanguageKeys(['en', 'fr'], {
        'en_US': 'en',
        'en_UK': 'en',
        'en_CA': 'en',
        'fr_FR': 'fr',
        'fr_CA': 'fr',
        'fr_BE': 'fr',
        '*': 'en'
    })
    .fallbackLanguage('en')
    .determinePreferredLanguage();

    // Add these lines to configure path 
    // and set the fallback language the same you defined above
    tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.localeLocationPattern('/base/node_modules/angular-i18n/angular-locale_{{locale}}.js');
    tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.defaultLocale('en');
})
```

You have to change `/base/node_modules/angular-i18n/` for the appropriate path. Also ensure the file naming convention is respected, for example by having `angular-locale_en.js` file in that directory.

### Then, from your **controller**, just call the `tmhDynamicLocale.set()` function with appropriate locale parameter.

On your code, it should look like:

```
this.changeLang = function () {
    $translate.use(self.currentLang).then(function (lang) {
       // This line will trigger the file change
       tmhDynamicLocale.set(lang);
    }, function () {
        MessageService.show("error", $translate.instant("lang_change_error"));
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explaination. Will try it